# Ubuntu 12.04 does not boot after installation

Tags: boot-failure, installation

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 by replacing my Windows installation. Everything worked perfectly. Then it asked me to restart. I did, but it does not go into a selection menu or start up menu. The screen is black and shows a blinking white stripe in the left top corner. Even after waiting 1 hour it did not start anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a new machine/laptop/netbook, then it may have "Secure Boot" switched on in the BIOS. In this case it may help to switch "Secure Boot" with [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) to off in the BIOS. You may also try [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)